# 7 women and 9 men are in the department at a school,select a committee of 5 members of the department if at least one women and man on the committee

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

**Seven women and nine men are on the faculty in the mathematics department at a school. $\\$
How many ways are there to select a committee of five members of the
department if at least one woman and at least one man must be on the committee?**

---

I know the solution and i understood that, we can do it using complement counting answer would be:  ${16 \choose 5} - {9\choose 5} - {7 \choose 5}= 4221$

---

But can anyone tell me, whats wrong with this ?
$\color{red} 
 {{9 \choose 1} \times {5 \choose 1} \times {14 \choose 3}}$ ways.                                                                                                           First selected exactly 1 man and 1 woman and then rest.

Comment: Suppose you select A and b initially, and C,d, E later. You could have also selected C,d first and A,b,E later. So there is overcounting. You can't *fractionate*

Comment: Yes, I got the mistake now...thnks :)
Even if u have provided this as solution, i could have accepted that :)

Comment: Fine, no sweat ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It counts multiple times the same team.For example it counts as different team the following 2 teams.

1)First pick John , then Mary and then Jane.

2)First pick John, then  Jane  and then Mary.

Comment: thnks :)
I got it